# Recovering normalized posterior distribution from log-posterior

Tags: bayesian, estimation, posterior, logarithm, numerical-models

For a Bayesian estimation problem that I am working on, where I update the log-posterior (many times based on data) instead of the posterior itself using Bayes rule. I find the following (rather convoluted) form of the log-posterior distribution

$$\text{lpos}(x) := -49949 \log(2) + \log(\exp\{-(1/8) (x-2)^2\}/(2 \sqrt{2 \pi})) + 
  114148 \log(\cos(x/2))\\ + 86056 \log(\sin(x/2)) + 99898 \log(\sin(x))$$

With the maximum numerically determined (using Mathematica) as -103515. and the minimum -130038.

I am trying to recover the posterior using the [The Log-Sum-Exp Trick](https://gregorygundersen.com/blog/2020/02/09/log-sum-exp/) but due to the large gap between the maximum and minimum I still get the error that "Exp[-26485.] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost".

Can anyone advise on how to work around this such that I can recover the **normalized posterior distribution** (as I am interested in the variance thereof) from such a convoluted log-posterior distribution? Many thanks for any assistance.

Comment: that's a problem of the number representation, not about the method you use. Exp[-26485.] is too small for single precision floating point, thus you might try to see if your language supports double precision numbers, or even more advanced precision numbers (though, you'll see a big increase in memory usage and a decrease in performance, as CPUs might not be very much optimized for such formats)

Comment: @Alberto Okay thanks for the comment. Any recommendations regarding languages? I am currently using Mathematica and Python.

Comment: Try giving a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html